# jQuery html imagem gallery zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery

Im trying to follow a "how to" to to implment a zoom on a image gallery.

The problem is that It works on the "example" provided by them, but it doesnt on my PC, I've done all things rigth i suppose.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
                $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
                $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
                $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
                $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
                $(".ajax").colorbox();
                $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
                $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
                $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                    onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                    onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                    onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                    onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                    onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
                });

                //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
                $("#click").click(function(){ 
                    $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>

<p><a class="group2" href="../images/slider/slide1.png" rel="thumbnail" title="This is beautiful castle for sale!"><img src="../images/slider/slide1.png" style="width: 150px; height: 100px" /></a></p>
```

So this make a thumbnail that when I click it should zoom in and "block" the background.

Ive this too:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.colorbox-mint.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But, when I click on the image that I want to zoom, it opens a new page with that image and I need to back again to my website :|

What im trying to do is this: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/

Comment: Hint: the anchor tag has `rel="thumbnail"` which does not appear in your jquery code.

Comment: is from another code, to create the thumbnails. But ive deleted that and still not working :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all that code...

You can edit the jquery to only one line:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
    });​
```

You also need to be certain you are placing script tags between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags of the page.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/r4BAJ/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works if I make link->open image. What I realy want is thumbnail image->open original image

Comment: Check my link above again.. I made it two images.. same code for colorbox.

Comment: I see it worked ! Thanks, but it still not work on my website :s Thumbnail is ok, but the another image still open on a new webpage instead of zoom itself

Comment: Then there must be other problems with other code on your site.

Comment: Ive figured it out! thanks ;) it was a <script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"> conflit with <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> I think!